# Angular, login, token, router

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-router

I'm working with Angular5 as Front and Symfony as Backend.

I have a login function like this, which is working:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<UserModel>
  return this.globalHttp.post('login', {username,password}).subscribe(
      data => {
        const token = token.data;
        this.setToken(token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/profiles-list");
        return Observable.of(data.user);
  });
}
```

So the function logs me in by setting the token in localstorage.

**But when the router navigate to /profiles-list, the token is still null.**

profiles-list.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.profileService.getProfiles();
}
```

profile.service.ts

```
getProfiles(): Observable<ProfileModel[]>
{
  return this.globalHttp.get('profiles',{});
}
```

global-http.service

```
token: string = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;

private _headers = {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token).set('Content-Type' : 'application/json')};

get( url: string, data?: any): Observable<any>
{
  return this.http.get(this.API_URL + url + this._headers)
}
```

I have to reload the page after login to make it work.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just declared `token` in your service. So when the service is initialized, token has no value and it will never be updated "by itself". Just fetch the token inside your `get` and set the headers:

```ts
get(url: string, data?: any): Observable<any> {
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
  let headers = {headers: new HttpHeaders()
                  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
                  .set('Content-Type' : 'application/json')};

  return this.http.get(this.API_URL + url + headers)
}
```

You could also move getting the token and setting headers in a separate method and just call that inside `get`-method (and all other possible methods).

Comment: Thanks, you were right. But in order to make it work, change .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token)  to .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)

Comment: Sure, you are correct, this happens when you copy paste code, which I did ;) Thanks for the remark, corrected it in answer :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to solve the problem like this :

global-http.service

```
export class GlobalHttpService
{
   token;
   headers;

   constructor (private http: HttpClient)
   {
     this.token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
     this.headers = {headers: new HttpHeaders()
                      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token)
                      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json)};
   }

   get( url:string, data?: any): Observable<any>
   {
     return this.http.get(this.API_URL + url + this.headers)
   }
```